# How to initialize an association object's field with multiple values using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy, associations

## Context

I have three tables, `Users`, `Subreddits`, and `Keywords`. The idea is that `users` can monitor multiple `subreddits`, and `subreddits` can monitor multiple `keywords`.

Since one user can monitor multiple subreddits, and one subreddit can have multiple users monitoring it, I would like to have a many-to-many relationship between `Users` and `Subreddits`.

On the same note, since one subreddit can monitor multiple keywords, and one keyword can be monitored by multiple subreddits, I would like to have a many-to-many relationship between `Subreddits` and `Keywords`.

I am using an `association object` as opposed to 2 `association tables`, since I have 3 tables that I want to relate with each other, while an association table is only for relationships between 2 tables.

## Implementation

The following is how I implemented each table, and the association object:

#### Users

```
class User(db.Model, JsonSerializer):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    phone_num = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    received_posts = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True)

    monitor = db.relationship('Monitor', back_populates='user')

    //...
```

#### Subreddits

```
class Subreddit(db.Model, JsonSerializer):
    __tablename__ = 'subreddits'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subreddit_name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)

    // ...
```

#### Keywords

```
class Keyword(db.Model, JsonSerializer):
    __tablename__ = 'keywords'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    keyword = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)

    monitor = db.relationship('Monitor', back_populates='keyword')

    // ...
```

### Association Object:

```
class Monitor(db.Model):
    __table_name__ = 'monitors'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=True)
    subreddit_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("subreddits.id"), nullable=True)
    keyword_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("keywords.id"), nullable=True)

    user = db.relationship('User', back_populates='monitor')
    subreddit = db.relationship('Subreddit')
    keyword = db.relationship('Keyword', back_populates='monitor')
```

## What I am Trying To Do

Ideally, every time a `user` tracks a `subreddit` and corresponding multiple `keywords`, all this information is stored into a `monitor` object.

For example,

- `user1` monitors `subreddit1`, which is keeping track of `keyword1` and `keyword2`.
- All these relationships should be stored in `monitor1`.

This should result in:

- monitor1.user = `user1`
- monitor1.subreddit = `subreddit1`
- monitor1.keyword = `keyword1, keyword2`

## What I've Tried

### Method #1

Initializing a `monitor` instance with a list of `keywords`.

```
# Parse the incoming data.
incoming = request.get_json()
subreddit_name = incoming["subredditName"]
subreddit_keywords = incoming["subredditKeywords"]
logged_in_user_id = incoming["id"]

# Query the User.
user = User.query.get(logged_in_user_id)

# Query the Subreddit.
subreddit = Subreddit.query.filter_by(subreddit_name=subreddit_name).first()

# Create a list of Keywords.
monitor_keywords = []
for kw in subreddit_keywords:
    # check if Keyword objects are in the database already
    if Keyword.query.filter_by(keyword=kw).first() is not None:
        keyword = Keyword.query.filter_by(keyword=kw).first()
    else: # create new Keyword objects
        keyword = Keyword(kw)
monitor_keywords.append(keyword)

# Create the monitoring1 association object.
monitor1 = Monitor(user=user, subreddit=subreddit, keyword=monitor_keywords) <----- Problem

db.session.add(monitor1)
db.session.commit()
```

I cannot initialize `monitor1` with `keyword=monitor_keywords`.

I receive the following error:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`.
Other submissions on Stack Overflow aren't relevant to my particular error case.

### Methods #2 to #5

I've tried initializing a `monitor` object first, then appending multiple `keywords` to it but this also did not work.

```
# Query the User
user = User.query.get(logged_in_user_id)

# Create the association object
monitor = Monitor(user=user, subreddit=None, keyword=None)
db.session.add(monitor)

// ...

for kw in subreddit_keywords:
    # check if Keyword objects are in the database already
    if Keyword.query.filter_by(keyword=kw).first() is not None:
        keyword = Keyword.query.filter_by(keyword=kw).first()
    else: # create new Keyword objects
        keyword = Keyword(kw)

    # Initialize monitor.keyword so we can append to it.
    if (monitor.keyword is None):
        monitor.keyword = keyword
    else: #All failed attempts to append to monitor.keyword.
        # monitor.keyword.append(keyword) <- Method #2    
        # keyword.append(monitor)         <- Method #3 
        # monitor.append(keyword)         <- Method #4  
        # user.monitor.append(keyword)    <- Method #5
```

## Problem

When I initialize an association object, I need to initialize it with multiple `keywords`.

Whether it's initializing the association object with the `keywords`, or later updating the association object with the `keywords`, it does not work. Ideally I'd like to stick with Method #1's approach, but I am open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused about your requirements but I think in this case it seems that maybe you mean for a user to listen for a specific keyword in a specific subreddit?  Which would mean that the association object would track one of each.  To make the plural easy maybe Monitor.  For column foreign keys it makes sense to name them with singular names.  In contrast to relationships which will either be plural or singular with a backref that is plural.

```py
class Monitor(db.Model):
    __table_name__ = 'monitors'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Singular
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=True)
    # Singular
    subreddit_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("subreddits.id"), nullable=True)
    # Singular
    keyword_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("keywords.id"), nullable=True)
    # Backref is all monitors for user across ALL subreddits and keywords.
    user = db.relationship('User', backref='monitors')
    # Backref is all monitors for subreddit across ALL users and keywords.
    subreddit = db.relationship('Subreddit', backref='monitors')
    # Backref is all monitors for keyword across ALL users and subreddits.
    keyword = db.relationship('Keyword', backref='monitors')
```

```
# Parse the incoming data.
incoming = request.get_json()
subreddit_name = incoming["subredditName"]
subreddit_keywords = incoming["subredditKeywords"]
logged_in_user_id = incoming["id"]

# Query the User.
user = User.query.get(logged_in_user_id)

# Query the Subreddit.
subreddit = Subreddit.query.filter_by(subreddit_name=subreddit_name).first()

# Create a list of Keywords.
for kw in subreddit_keywords:
    # Create Keyword in database (this is another problem if you want the names to be unique)
    keyword = Keyword(keyword=kw)
    # The subreddit and keyword this user is watching.
    db.session.add(Monitor(user=user, subreddit=subreddit, keyword=keyword))

db.session.commit()

# All subreddit/keyword pairs being watched by this user.
monitors = db.query(Monitor).filter(Monitor.user == user).all()

# All keywords being watched for this subreddit for this user
monitored_kws = db.query(Keyword).join(Keyword.monitors).filter(Monitor.user == user, Monitor.subreddit == subreddit).all()
```

Comment: For people that may face my same problem, the misconception was trying to add an array of children (Keyword) to a parent (Monitor), but the actual approach is to create a parent PER child. So for keywords: `keyword1, keyword2` on `subreddit1`, these should be created:`subreddit1, subreddit1` and `Monitor1, Monitor1`. Then, we can fetch all Children (Keyword) by querying the Parent: `Monitor.query.join(Monitor.subreddit).filter(Monitor.subreddit=='subreddit1')` which will return 2 Monitor objects:`Monitor1.keyword== keyword1` and `Monitor1.keyword==keyword2`.